Export random forest model with skompiler exceeding recursion limit
I have a random forest model that I've trained in Python 3.12.0 with scikit-learn 1.3.0.  I'm trying to, then export the model weights to Excel with skompiler 0.7.  I'm getting the RecursionError below when I run the code below.
Do you have any idea what the issue might be, and can you suggest how to fix it?  rf is the pretrained random forest model.
code:
from skompiler import skompile
from skompiler.fromskast.excel import excel_range


expr = skompile(rf.predict,excel_range(f"B3:BQ3")


code = expr.to('excel', multistage=True, assign_to=exccel_range('BT3:*3'))

error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded


Is this question about Python version 3? Otherwise, please use the more general tag "python" instead of "python-3.x"
